# How to set time in hh:mm format in TimePicker Dialog.

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I am currently using a TimePickerDialog to set the time and display it into a Edit Text .However, I am having problems with the formating.

I want to set the time in HH:MM format but it is set like H:mm format
i want this  01:33 but my code giving me 1:33 output.

Here is the code :-

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

        String am_pm = "";

        Calendar datetime1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        datetime1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        datetime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        if (datetime1.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
            am_pm = "AM";
        else if (datetime1.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
            am_pm = "PM";

        String strHrsToShow1 = (datetime1.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 00)?"12":datetime1.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"";

        ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText( strHrsToShow1+":"+datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm);

    }
```

Comment: may be not because that question not giving me the answer.

Comment: Try `((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText( String.format("%02d:%02d", strHrsToShow1, datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) +" "+am_pm);`

Comment: So have you tried the code in that answer? What happened? This definitely looks like a duplicate to me: in both cases, the code in the question just converts the integer to the string directly (so it won't be 0-padded) and the answer should either be to apply zero-padding yourself (to minutes as well as hours) or to use date/time formatting to do it for you.

Comment: @Dejvid giving me error like  java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Comment: @WealInfotech Probably because `datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` returns int instead of string. Try `((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setTex‌​t( String.format("%02d:%02d", strHrsToShow1, datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "") +" "+am_pm);`

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried that question's answer but none are helping me so that i put the question here.

Comment: @Dejvid giving me the same error

Comment: You should say exactly what you tried and what happened then. I very much doubt that the accepted answer on that question would give you the same behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried that answer and giving me the same error java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Comment: So will you please unmark my question from duplicate?@JonSkeet

Comment: No, because you should show exactly what you tried in the question. It sounds like you're trying to format values which are already strings, instead of formatting the integers. If you **show that code** we can help you fix it. It really *is* the same problem and it really *does* have the same solution, you've just not applied that solution properly.

Comment: okay @JonSkeet i got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line:

```
txtTime1.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", strHrsToShow1, datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
```

Instead of:

```
((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText( strHrsToShow1+":"+datetime1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm);
```

Comment: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String giving error like this

Comment: String tm = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(time));

Comment: @sapanravani "56" what is (new Date(time))?

Comment: Date is inbuilt class in android..you have to pass time as a parameter and it will convert to the format passed in SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").

Comment: @sapanravani please explain with some code 56

Comment: but its a DatePicker and i am using TimePicker see my question and why don't you writing the answer instead of commenting?

Comment: just want to add one line         int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
  ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour,
                minute, hourOfDay < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));